# Listing items by the category they belong to

Tags: python, django

I'm a complete Newb so please bear with me. I've never used OOP or a framework before.

I'm creating a book keeping system where I want the ledgers to be displayed by the category they belong to. Here's my model and it seems to work:

```
class COAGroup(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name

class Ledger(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    COAGroup = models.ForeignKey(COAGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

I'm working on my first view which should list all the ledgers by the category they belong to. Eg

```
<h2>Some COAGroup Name</h2>
<ul>
 <li>A ledger that belongs to this group</li>
 <li>Another ledger that belonds to the group</li>
 <li>And another</li>
</ul>

<h2>Another COAGroup</h2>
<ul>
 <li>A ledger that belongs to this second group</li>
 <li>Another ledger</li>
</ul>
```

I've written the following view in views.py:

```
def showledgers(request):  
    COAGroups = COAGroup.objects.all()
    Ledgers = Ledger.objects.all()
    context = {
        "COAGroups":COAGroups,
        "Ledgers":Ledgers,
    }
    return render(request,"ListLedgers.html",context)
```

I've  managed to get the ledgers to show in ListLedgers.html but I can't figure out how to get them to list by COA Group as per my example.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you read the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-for)?

Answer (score 0):

In your view, you better already [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) the related `Ledger`s:

```
def showledgers(request):  
    COAGroups = COAGroup.objects.prefetch_related('ledger')
    context = {
        'groups': COAGroups,
    }
    return render(request, 'ListLedgers.html', context)
```

Then in the template, you can iterate over the `COAGroups`, and for each such group over the related `.ledger_set`:

```
{% for group in groups %}
  <h2>{{ group.Name }}</h2>
  <ul>
  {% for ledger in group.ledger_set.all %}
    <li>{{ ledger.name }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PerlCase*, so it should be: `name` instead of <s>`Name`</s>.

Comment: Thank you, that almost worked. I didn't need to do the prefetch (that code errored) but the group.ledger_set.all bit did the trick. I've also converted all my fields to snake_case as you advised, and looked up other such conventions so I'm writing correctly from the start.